# Como tornar acessíveis as propriedades de um User Control no XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controles

Um **User Control** pode ser utilizado para diversos fins, mas gostaria de saber especificamente um exemplo simples de como se criaria um **User Control** qualquer que retornasse um valor qualquer.

Por exemplo um **NumericUpDown**:

[image: Imagem de um Flat NumericUpDown]

Criado a partir deste código **XAML**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TCC_2.Templates.NumericUpDown1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TCC_2.Templates"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="40" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid1" MouseWheel="Grid_MouseWheel">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="txtValue" DataObject.Pasting="TextBoxPasting" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Text="0" FontSize="18" Grid.RowSpan="2" Foreground="#444" PreviewTextInput="txtValue_PreviewTextInput" TextChanged="txtValue_TextChanged" />

        <Button x:Name="btnIncrease" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="#444" FontSize="10" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#ccc" Content="▲"  BorderThickness="0" Cursor="Hand" Click="btnIncrease_Click"  />

        <Button x:Name="btnDecrease" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="DarkGray" FontSize="10" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Content="▼" BorderThickness="0" Cursor="Hand" Height="20"  Click="btnDecrease_Click" />
        </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Com esses métodos principais em **C#**:

```
    private void btnIncrease_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        value++;
        txtValue.Text = value.ToString();
        btnDecrease.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(color);
        btnDecrease.IsEnabled = true;
    } 

    private void btnDecrease_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (value > 0)
        {
            if (value == 1)
            {
                btnDecrease.Foreground = Brushes.DarkGray;
                btnDecrease.IsEnabled = false;
            }
            value--;
            txtValue.Text = value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

A questão é... digamos que eu coloque esse Controle em uma página **XAML**...
Como eu faço para obter o texto de dentro da **TextBox txtValue** ?

Chamando no código da página por exemplo o "**NumericUpDown1.Text**"

Eu já tentei utilizar este **Binding** na propriedade **Text** da TextBox:
`Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=Text}"`

Porém na página ao se chamar essa propriedade ela não existe.

Então como faço para obter esse valor ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para dotar um *UserControl* com propriedades que possam ser acedidas via código C# ou XAML deve implementá-las como [DependencyProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428(v=vs.110).aspx).

A implementação consiste na propriedade(*CLR property*) que quer aceder e uma propriedade(uma instância do tipo *DependencyProperty*) resultante do seu registo no *"WPF property system"*.

No presente caso declare a propriedade assim:

```
public int Value
{
    get { return (int)this.GetValue(StateProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(StateProperty, value); } 
}
```

e a *DependencyProperty* assim:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Value", typeof(int), typeof(NumericUpDown1),new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

Mais informação em [Dependency Properties Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx).